# Mishna Berurah - Oz VeHadar or Dirshu

Tags: product-recommendation, mishnah-berurah

I am looking to buy a Mishnah Berurah set. The Oz VeHadar and the Dirshu sets look like good options. Does anyone have a recommendation to offer for one set over the other? Or is there another set that is even better? I am looking for a set that has very clear type, nice binding, and is not too large in size.

Comment: Check out Dovid Lichtenstein's Mishnah Acharonah https://hebrewbooks.org/50327

Comment: The regular cheap editions are also very good options. That's what I have and they work very well.

Comment: It it for learning or reference? I have both the classic "cheap edition" (as 2AA calls it above) and the Dirshu. I find the classic one to be easier for learning (I do amud yomi) as it is larger. Dirshu is excellent for reference and researching specific questions due to the many additional modern opinions, but I find it a bit small font. This is likely personal, I'm 49 and don't have the best eyes. Both have clear types and nice bindings. "Not too large" is completely personal